# Azure Cognitive service intents and entities api needed

Tags: azure, api, rest, azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services

I am working with node js. Now I have to connect my application with Azure Cognitive Services. I did not find APIs for detecting Intent , API for listing Intent also API for listing entities. Right now I am using axios to send request from my node js applications. I tried [LUIS](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/luis-programmatic-apis-v3-0-preview/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c2f) documentation. But this does not work. Then I have tried [Azure Cognitive service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/language/) documentation. It works but there I did not find any api for intents and entities. Which api documentation should I follow and is there any better way to connect Azure Cognitive service with
node js?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where you were looking for, but Node (Javascript) has a valid SDK for Azure Services, including Cognitive Services.

Please check the official doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/azure/ai-text-analytics-readme?view=azure-node-latest

And here's the official npm:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/ai-text-analytics

Comment: I need api for listing intents and entities. Is there any api in Azure cognitive service(Language Studio)?

Comment: Intents and Entities are part of the Text analytics.

Answer (score 0):

To get the intents and entities [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/language/2022-10-01-preview/conversational-analysis-authoring/get-model-evaluation-summary?tabs=HTTP) api help me.
**Endpoint**:

```
GET {Endpoint}/language/authoring/analyze-conversations/projects/{projectName}/models/{trainedModelLabel}/evaluation/summary-result?api-version=2022-10-01-preview
```

Change the projectName with your project title and the trainedModelLabel with a trained model title.